# Drawing Line at current position using QGraphicsLineItem

Tags: qt

I want to draw a line using QGraphicsLineItem. What exactly I want is that on clicking at GraphicsView, after second click Line must be drawn. I am confused with the syntax of QGraphicsLineItem and also how to use it. I am new to Qt. Please help me out to solve this problem.

Comment: Please show the code you have. Make sure it's short - put it all into a single main.cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code snippet.

*h

```
#ifndef GRAPHICSSCENE_H
#define GRAPHICSSCENE_H

#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QStack>
#include <QPoint>
#include <QMouseEvent>
class GraphicsScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit GraphicsScene(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent);
public slots:
    private:

    QStack<QPoint> stack;

};

#endif // GRAPHICSSCENE_H
```

*.cpp

```
#include "graphicsscene.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>

GraphicsScene::GraphicsScene(QObject *parent) :
    QGraphicsScene(parent)
{
}

void GraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
    qDebug() << "in";
    if (mouseEvent->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        QPoint pos = mouseEvent->scenePos().toPoint();


        if(stack.isEmpty())
            stack.append(pos);
        else if(stack.count() == 1)
        {
            stack.append(pos);
            addLine(QLine(stack.pop(),stack.pop()),QPen(Qt::green));
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
GraphicsScene *scene = new GraphicsScene(this);
ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
ui->graphicsView->show();
```

Edit: more beautiful solution which works as you need.

```
void GraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
    qDebug() << "in";
    if (mouseEvent->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        QPoint pos = mouseEvent->scenePos().toPoint();

        if(stack.isEmpty())
            stack.append(pos);
        else
            addLine(QLine(pos,stack.pop()),QPen(Qt::green));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can derive the graphics view/scene and override the mousePressEvent

Below is example using derived QGraphicsScene and overridden mousePressEvent

Class Definition :

```
class MyScene : public QGraphicsScene
```

Data Members :

```
QList<QPointF> m_clickPositions;
int m_mode;
```

Code :

```
void MyScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(false == sceneRect().contains(event->scenePos()))
    {
        QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(event);
    }
    else if(Qt::LeftButton == event->button() && m_mode == ConstructMode)
    {
        m_clickPositions.append(event->scenePos());

        if(m_clickPositions.size() == 2)
        {
            QLineF lineF(m_clickPositions[0], m_clickPositions[1]);
            QGraphicsLineItem* item = this->addLine(lineF);
            m_clickPositions.clear();
            m_mode = ScrollMode;
        }

    }
}
```

I had used something similar in my project and extracted the code. Hope this helps.
Please comment is this is not working.

Edit ::
ConstructMode and Scroll mode are used in the above program so that I can distinguish whether I want to Draw/Construct or just scroll the scene. You can remove them and the declaration of m_mode if not required by you.

If you want to use the modes you can define some public constants and add a method setMode(). Please see the code below.

MyScene.h or some Constant file if you have one

```
#define ConstructMode 100
#define ScrollMode 101
```

And add the following function

```
void MyScene::setMode(int mode)
{
    m_mode = mode;
}
```

After this if you want to enter the construction mode you will need to call myScene->setMode(ConstructMode) everytime, as after the item is constructed the mode is reset to ScrollMode.

Comment: I used this code but getting following :1) error: 'ConstructMode' was not declared in this scope
2)error: 'ScrollMode' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Please help me out. I am not getting where and how to declare constructmode and Scrollmode

Comment: ScrollMode and ConstructMode were used by me to distinguish whether I am in Construct/Draw Mode or whether I just want to scroll the scene. You can delete them if they are not required by you. (Delete the m_mode declaration also ).